# How to make an animated png from bmp files?

Tags: c++, c, image, bash

How can I convert 1.bmp 2.bmp ... n.bmp (each 24 bpp) into a single mng or apng file (with animation) in bash/cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program can create APNG from TGA/PNG sequences:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/apngasm/files/